# Extract plain text from HTML text in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have used a rich textbox control,ckeditor in my case,When any formatting is done to the text the formatted text is populated in the datagrid.But I want to extract only the plain text in the grid and trim the length of data to 80 characters while populating.

The query for updating the answer is as follows

```
    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtEditorAnswer.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
        {

            int intIsUpdated = 0;
            string strUpdateQuery = "UPDATE M_QA SET ANSWER = '" + txtEditorAnswer.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''")
                                  + "', UPDATED_ON = getDate(), UPDATED_BY = '" + this.Session["UserId"].ToString()
                                  + "' WHERE PK_ID = " + _currentQuestionId + " AND IS_ACTIVE = 1";
```

and the query for populating data in the grid is as follows:

```
    protected void LoadQA(int intQuestionId)
    {
        string strSelectQuery = "SELECT REPLACE(TITLE, '\n', '<br />') TITLE, REPLACE(DESCRIPTION, '\n', '<br />') DESCRIPTION, "
                                + "ANSWER, FK_OWNER_ID, CREATED_ON FROM M_QA WHERE PK_ID = "
                                + intQuestionId + " AND IS_ACTIVE = 1";
```

can plz some buddy help me!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [HTML agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), parse your query result on ItemDataBound event then select only the text() nodes to display